# Passing variable to controller method from route

Tags: laravel-8

I have the following Route defined in my .php files

```
Route::get("search/cityNames",[\App\Http\Controllers\SearchController::class,'getCitiesListForSearch']);
```

I want, from the Route line in the .php file, to send a variable to the getCitiesListForSearch method. I want to send a variable called 'dev' and set it to 'true'/'false' from the code, not from the link used to access the endpoint.

Is there any way to pass the variable or do I need to make the call in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was much easier than I expected.
I had to change the route to this:

```
Route::get("search/cityNames",
[
    'version' => 1,
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\SearchController@getCitiesListForSearch'
]);
```

and in my method, after putting `Request $request` as a parameter:

```
$action = $req->route()->getAction();
echo $action['version'];
```

and I was able to access that.